# find and replace application - F&R multiple strings in one text

Tags: php, replace

Hei. I would very much appreciate some help with this. I am creating a very simple "find and replace" application to generate links. I am using the code below to do this.

It now replaces the word "chocolate" with anything I'd like. But i would also like to change other words within the same text with the push of the same button.

Forexample; if i would like to change the word "loves" to "hates" as well.

How would i do this? Appreciate all the help i can get.

```html
<?php
$offset=0;
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['searchfor']) && isset($_POST['replacewith']))
{
$text=$_POST['text'];
$search=$_POST['searchfor'];
$replace=$_POST['replacewith'];
$search_length=strlen($search);
    if(!empty($text)&&!empty($search)&&!empty($replace))
    {
        $strpos=strpos($text,$search);
$text=substr_replace($text,$replace,$strpos,$search_length);
echo $new = str_replace(' ', '%20', $text);

    }
    else
    {
    echo 'pls fill in all fields';
    }
}

?>
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
<textarea name='text' style="display:none;" rows='6' cols='30'>http://andy.com/loves/chocolate/cake</textarea><br><br>
<input type='hidden' value= 'chocolate' name='searchfor'><br><br>
Replace the word chocolate with:</br>
<input type='text' name='replacewith'><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='find and replace'>
</form>
```

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, then you can use the same function `str_replace` for multiple replacements using the array as parameters. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrays in str_replace, so this code will work using 2 comma separated valus in the input field:

```
    $offset=0;
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['searchfor']) && isset($_POST['replacewith']))
{
    $text=$_POST['text'];
    $search=explode(",",$_POST['searchfor']);
    $replace=explode(",",$_POST['replacewith']);
    var_dump($replace);

    $text=str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
    echo $text;
}

<form action='#' method='POST'>
<textarea name='text' style="display:none;" rows='6' cols='30'>http://andy.com/loves/chocolate/cake </textarea><br><br>
<input type='hidden' value= 'chocolate,cake' name='searchfor'><br><br>
Replace the word chocolate with:</br>
<input type='text' name='replacewith'><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='find and replace'>
```

If you want to use 2 (or more) input fields use this code:

```
$offset=0;
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['searchfor']) && isset($_POST['replacewith']))
{
    $text=$_POST['text'];
    $search=explode(",",$_POST['searchfor']);
    $replace=array($_POST['replacewith'],$_POST['replacewith2']);
    var_dump($replace);

    $text=str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
    echo $text;
}


<form action='#' method='POST'>
<textarea name='text' style="display:none;" rows='6' cols='30'>http://andy.com/loves/chocolate/cake </textarea><br><br>
<input type='hidden' value= 'chocolate,cake' name='searchfor'><br><br>
Replace the word chocolate with:</br>
<input type='text' name='replacewith'><br>
Replace the word cake with:</br>
<input type='text' name='replacewith2'><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='find and replace'>
```

Comment: note that I removed your controls, just add them again and add what is needed to this new version.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works but when entering the values to be replaced i would like them to be seperated by a new text input instead of a comma.

Comment: You are welcome Andy and welcome to Stackoverflow. I've updated my answer. Please accept it and upvote if you find it useful.